# Can't control brightness on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, intel-graphics, brightness

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Inspiron 11 3162 laptop with 1.6Ghz Intel Celeron 64 bit, 2GB DDR3 and 29GB EMMC storage and it works fine as per my requirements. But I can't control brightness on it.

Its stuck on full.

When I see driver, it shows only `dell_backlight`. I have tried solutions like adding `acpi_backlight=vendor`, `acpi_backlight=video` in grub but it doesn't work. I found solutions for editing files in `X11` but its for `intel_backlight` driver. I have `xorg` installed but that doesn't help too.

I tried using `xrandr` commands to set brightness but that doesn't work.
I installed Brightness Controller but that doesn't work either.

My laptop has keyboard keys which control brightness. Unless I set `acpi_backlight=vendor` the brightness slider and the buttons don't appear. They appear but changing them doesn't reduce/increase brightness.

In settings, it shows unknown display.

The output of `lshw` indicates Intel display.
There aren't any updates pending for software and drivers, BIOS doesn't have any display related setting.

Dell doesn't have any drivers listed for the laptop for linux.

I installed Linux Mint 20, xubuntu 18.04, lubuntu 18.04 and tried everything above but same problem.

Help.

Answer (score -3):

Use this command `kernel --set-brightness 50%`. It will command the kernel to change the brightness to your desired %.

Comment: It says invalid command.

Comment: It is a invalid command, kindly confirm before posting in the public forum.